# tvOS, tvjs: How to hook into MediaPlayer (...)/"more" button?

Tags: javascript, audio, tvos, tvjs

While playing audio using the std. tvOS/tvjs media player "touching" the remote will let you navigate to the (...) or "More" button.

[image]

I am trying to catch the button press and display a menu overlay in play tvjs/javascript - so far without much success. Tvjs error out with the following msg: `Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UIAlertController: 0x7f88eaf2be80>)`

Apple's documentation doesn't seem to explain that... I even tried adding an event listener (on `select` and/or `play`) on the player itself (well, it's not documented that way... but was my last shot :-)

Does anybody have an idea on how to hook into this button? I really would appreciate any help!

PS: The rest of the code can be viewed at https://github.com/iBaa/PlexConnectApp/blob/master/PlexConnectApp/js/AudioPlayer.js.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this actually was a tvOS limitation, which got fixed with v9.2...